# PIG : Give value to a tweets

Tags: hadoop, twitter, apache-pig, hiveql

My goal, it's to rate a tweets in Pig Latin.
I have 3 list of words to use as dictionnary (positive words, negative words and irrelevant words).
I would to rate a list of tweets with this dictionary. I have to analyse each word of a tweet.
I have to rate tweets by search "growth in France"

Example :

- List positive words : {good,positive,great,...}
- List negative words : {bad,recession,...}
- List irrelevant words : {Germany, Spain, Hollande, Obama,...}

A tweet : "Growth in France is back again and in Spain too" => analyse for each word :
growth => positive, France => positive, again => positive, Spain => irrelevant
So this tweet is positive and relevant because positive + positive + positive + irrelevant = positive

I tried to make this script ...
Sorry for english

Comment: What is your question though? Here in Xplenty, we've just done some Twitter analysis for the Sochi Winter Olympics, including a naive sentiment analysis similar to what you described. Where did you encounter difficulties?

Comment: In writting the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outlines of what your script should look like:

1. Extract the tweet ID and the text field from the tweeter stream.
2. To the ID and text add another field by using flatten and tokenize - tokenize the text into words (you can use a simple white space tokenizer or something fancier NLTK and break each word in a new record.
3. Join the output of (2) with your dictionary to tag each word in your tweets as positive, negative or neutral/irrelevant - you might want to use a signed integer value instead of positive/negative so it'll be easier for you to add them up.
4. group the result of (3) by tweet ID.
5. calculate the sum of sentiment per Tweet.

   TweetsRaw = LOAD '...' USING JsonLoader(...);

   ...

   Tweets = FOREACH ... GENERATE TweetID, Text;

   TokenizedTweets = FOREACH Tweets GENERATE TweetID, Text, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(Text)) as word;

   Dictionary = LOAD '...' as (DictWord: chararray, polarity: int);

   Labeled_Words = JOIN TokenizedTweets BY Word, Dictionary BY DictWord;

   GroupedSentiment = GROUP Labeled_Words BY TwitterID, Text;

   Result = FOREACH GroupedSentiment GENERATE FLATTEN(group), SUM(Labeled_Words.polarity) AS rate;

   DUMP Result;